# Uniform bound on integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow [ 0, 1 ]$ be a measurable function and let $( \mu_n )_{ n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a sequence of positive measures on $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^d}))$ such that
$$
\int_{ \mathbb{R}^d } f(x) \mu_n(dx) < \infty, \quad \int_{ \mathbb{R}^d } f^2 (x) \mu_n(dx) < \infty, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Further assume that there is some $C > 0$ such that
$$
\int_{ \mathbb{R}^d } f^2 (x) \mu_n(dx) < C \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. \tag{1}
$$

> Is it possible to show that there also exists some $M > 0$ such that $$\int_{ \mathbb{R}^d } f (x) \mu_n(dx) < M \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \quad ? \tag{2}$$

Since $f^2 \leq f$, $(2)$ would clearly imply $(1)$. But is the converse true? If we instead consider a positive sequence $( a_n )_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$
a_n^2 \leq C \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N},
$$
then also
$$
a_n \leq \sqrt{ C } \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Can something similar be done for $(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counterexample, take $d=1$, define $f(x) = \min\{1,|x|^{-1/2}\}$, and define $\mu_n(x)$ to be Lebesgue measure restricted to $[4^n,4^{n+1}]$. Then $\int_{ \mathbb{R} } f(x)^2\, d\mu_n(x) = \int_{4^n}^{4^{n+1}} 1/x \, dx = \log 4$ for all $n$, but $\int_{ \mathbb{R} } f(x)\, d\mu_n(x) = \int_{4^n}^{4^{n+1}} 1/\sqrt x \, dx = 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: $f$ should lie within $[0,1]$. In your example, that is the case only for $x≥1$, but it is irrelevant, since you have restricted the measure, right? It also seems that the value of the second integral should be $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Corresponding edits made.